# Solidity if condition based mapping with multiple struct

Tags: solidity, contract-design, mapping, struct

I'm trying to map with more than one structs. First mapping contains common details need to be mapped to every item and then second mapping should be carried out according to the item type.

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
    contract MyContract {

     struct CommonDetails {
      string name; 
      uint32 group;
      mapping (string => SpecificDetails1) items;
     }

     struct SpecificDetails1{
      uint32 capacity;
      string owner;
     }

    struct SpecificDetails2{
     uint32 capacity;
     string owner;
    }

    mapping (address => CommonDetails) commonMapping;
    mapping (string => address)specificMapping;

    function setName(string _name, uint32 _group){

     commonMapping[tx.origin] = CommonDetails(_name, _group);

      if (_group == 1){
       // add SpecificDetails1 along with existing common details
       // if _group == 2 then add SpecificDetails2
     }
    }

   function getName() constant returns(address, string, uint32) {

     return (tx.origin, commonMapping[tx.origin].name, 
     commonMapping[tx.origin].group);
     // also want SpecificDetails in getter function
    }
```

Initially, common details should be mapped to every item and then according to the input (for the group), 2nd struct should be mapped.

I have tried to create an array within struct and then push the specific details to that array but no joy.

My question is how can we perform 2nd mapping to another struct that is based on the input getting from the initial mapping?

If this is not possible within the single contract, can we do this importing this contract function into another contract and then perform 2nd mapping?
And also how to get the output of both mapping in getter function, also.

Any guidance would definitely be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need 2 different structs containing the exact same properties?

Comment: The first struct contains some common details that I want to attach to every item. With the second struct, I want to attach some specific details. Let's take the example of student where every student has some common details and then based on student's major subject, we may attach some additional details.

I'm not sure if a mapping within struct will help in this regard? But I want to make it 'if condition' based as described above in the comments within the code.

Comment: and these properties will contain different values depending upon the item, in spite of having same properties names but values will be different. Here just for the example, I used the same property names, but of course, names can be different.

Comment: Can modifier help here?

Comment: If we use the "student and class" example, you are describing a many-to-many relationship. That would be traditionally represented in three tables, one about the students, one about the classes (these have the "common" fields, and one about the intersection between students and classes where things like enrollment date, grade, date completed, etc., would reside. This is normalized design. Does that sound like what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, so every student must have all the properties (common fields) from the class table and then they have their own specific properties as well.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve through _inheritance_ in the following way:
`pragma solidity ^0.4.19;
contract CommonContract{
    string name;
    function CommonContract(string _name){
        name = _name;
    }
}
contract SpecificContract is CommonContract{
    uint32 capacity;
    function SpecificContract(string _name, uint32 _capacity) CommonContract(_name){
        capacity = _capacity;
    }
    function getDetails()constant returns(string, uint32){
        return(name, capacity);
    }
}`

Comment: but I can't see setters and getters created for this function in remix, even this is without mapping and struct.

Comment: I would suggest a system of three contracts. Students, Classes, and Enrollments. The third table is of course the glue. Each object (row) will have a student address, a class I'd, and then other details pertaining to the join - things that are not the same in every case of that student or every case of that class. This is relational database design. I might caution against overloading contracts with storage burdens that can be attended to off chain at lower cost.

Comment: How can we implement relational design through solidity? is that possible to achieve this using inheritance? The code I posted in above comment does not produce the desired output.